# Long query string variable missing

Tags: php, apache, query-string

I've got a pretty long query string variable (value is approximately 600 chars) that I'm trying to reach from a PHP script. The long one is not present in `$_REQUEST` or `$_GET` but another variable with shorter value length is. I've shaved off some of it to test and it starts going missing when the value is at 549 chars or more.

Fortunately the long variable is present in `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` so for now I'm just picking it up from there, but was curious as to if this is a server setting (Apache 2) or something with my PHP setup (5.2.17) or script?

BTW, the query string itself is not something I control so unfortunately I can't change how that works, for ex. sending via POST.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you have a [hardend/suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html) version of php. It provides configuration directives to limit the length of names and values for input parameters.

> #### suhosin.get.max_name_length
>
> ```
>     Type: Integer
>     Default: 64
> ```
>
> Defines the maximum length of variable names for variables registered through the URL. For array variables this is the name in front of the indices.
>
> #### suhosin.get.max_totalname_length
>
> ```
>     Type: Integer
>     Default: 256
> ```
>
> Defines the maximum length of the total variable name when registered through the URL. For array variables this includes all indices.
>
> #### suhosin.get.max_value_length
>
> ```
>     Type: Integer
>     Default: 512
> ```
>
> Defines the maximum length of a variable that is registered through the URL.

Comment: Awesome, I think this is it VolkerK. I don't have access to php.ini on this particular server so will stick with parsing it out from $_SERVER for now.

Comment: Hopefully you're using parse_str(,$arr) for that ;-)

Comment: Yup, parse_str($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], $looooong_queries); heheh

Comment: Oh, and thanks for link, haven't used Suhosin personally, good to catch up on.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this in PHP 5.4 in Debian Wheezy, which does not use suhosin.  I finally found this user note buried on [the `parse_str()` page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php#108642) that `max_input_vars` in php.ini setting controls the number of variables `parse_str()` will read in this version of PHP.

Also note that `max_input_vars` applies even if you are using the CLI runtime.

Comment: This took me ages to find out. Wouldn't have found it out if it weren't for this comment! Thanks